# Change Source URL of Charts in C3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, datetimepicker, c3.js

I have a webpage which shows charts using C3.js. The source of data is a url. Now i want to add functionality of bootstrap date time picker, so that i can make query for data after a particular timestamp. On selecting the date and submitting it. the source url should be changed, it should contain a query parameter for timestamp.
Is this possible with C3.js, refreshing the source url.
How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.load();` API function to refresh the chart. see live example [here](http://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html)

It should looks like :

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        url: '/data/c3_test.csv'
    }
});

//later in the code
//#timestamp is your datetime picker element
$('#timestamp').on('change', function(){
    chart.load({
        url: '/data/c3_test2.csv'
    });
});
```

Comment: this is what, i was looking for. Thanks